# How to publish js + assets files to npm

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-publish, npm-package

I've developed a small Ui component for internal use in a company and published it to npm but when I install that package I only get an `index.js` file in `node_modules` folder.

I'm not using any package builder, es-modules, just a straightforward `.js` and `.css`

The folder i want to publish as the package has the following structure:

```
package
 - src
   - index.js
   - index.css
   - assets/
     - fonts/
       - ..some fonts
     - images/
       - icon.svg
 - package.json
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`npm publish --dry-run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-publish#dry-run) to see what `npm` thinks it should be publishing. (Another possibility is to use `npm pack` and then examine the contents of the resulting tarball.)

If you have files missing, check the contents of any relevant `.npmignore` file or a `.gitignore` file, either of which might cause `npm` to ignore a file. (Read the [relevant npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) if you are not familiar with how that all works.)

Lastly, check your `package.json` to see if there is a `files:` entry, "which is an array of file or directory names that should be included in your package" (according to the docs previously linked). If you have a `files:` entry, add the files you want published that aren't being included.